# Custom & Proprietary service issue

Tags: sql-server, windows-services, windows-server-2008

We have a windows 2008 box with few windows services; and the services start-up type is Automatic. The concern is that, not all services (with automatic start up type) starts on successful server restart. Any idea ?

We noticed the aforementioned issue on service particularly custom windows service, SQL server related services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each service will need to be troubleshooted separately. Are any errors [reported to the Event Log](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#DiagnoseProblems)?

Perhaps your service is starting too soon, before other necessary services have been initialized. You may need to set up a dependency or set the Startup type to **Automatic (Delayed Start)** from the [the Services Control Panel](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/services-control-panel-startup-type.jpg).